# How to setup ElasticSearch for multiple cluster (not multi node in single cluster)?

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing

I am looking for setting up multi cluster ES as below.

cluster.name: mycluster1

cluster.name: mycluster2

The configurations for both the cluster being same.
cluster2 will be in other data center for disaster recovery. 
How do I co-relate cluster1 & cluster2.

Does ES provide any configuration param to support this?

Answer (score 1):

I think using a tribe node to communicate with your 2 clusters is the best option.
The configuration is something like this :

```
 node.name: any-name
 node.master: false
 node.data: false
 tribe:
    t1: 
        cluster.name: mycluster1
        discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1"]
        discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false 

    t2: 
        cluster.name: mycluster2
        discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host2"]
        discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

But, not really sure if it's a good idea to have different clusters in different data-centers. https://www.elastic.co/blog/clustering_across_multiple_data_centers